# How can I create a subdirectory that is a datetime stamp of the format YYYMMDDHHMMSS?

Tags: linux, bash, date, timestamp, mkdir

How can I create a subdirectory using BASH shell that is a datetime stamp of the format YYYMMDDHHMMSS?  I am using  `` mkdir ~/$(printf "%s" `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`) `` but keep getting unprintable characters ('?') on the end.  Linux 2.6.18

Answer (score 1):

You're don't need the `printf` to strip off newlines, `$()` will do that for you (see [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution))

```
mkdir ~/$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

To see what those unprintable chars are (you may have a trailing carriage return), try this:

```
for dir in 2013*; do printf "%s" "$dir" | od -c; done
```

Comment: I tried this and still got a trailing '?' (unprintable char) using `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` worked.  Apostrophe (`) not single quote (')

Comment: Glenn, Your solution is working now.  I could've sworn it wasn't earlier.  Never ran the 'od' command, was in too much of a hurry to find solution.  Thank you for the help and sorry I can't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

What about using :

```
DIR_NAME="/Your_Path/"mydir`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
or
printf `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`// Displaying 20130429173838
```

Comment: Same for this. [I tried this and still got a trailing '?' (unprintable char) using `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` worked.  Apostrophe (`) not single quote (')]